# Multiple colors in NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to change the color for words that are repeating in each line in NSTextField.
I'm using dictionary to separate each line and the dictionary has and array which separates words as data, then i'm checking if the words are repeated and i want to change color or highlight the words that are repeating.. not sure how to do it.

The program is to get word frequency and show type-token, mean frequency and words that are repeating (text colour/highlighted)

any help would be great. right now i'm assigning text to text field from the .txt file imported. got the repeating words and everything.. just need to show which.

current code:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary*) computeWords:(NSMutableDictionary *)linesDic{
    int count = (int)[linesDic count];
    int numberOfwords = 0;
    int numberOfDiffWords = 0;
    NSMutableDictionary* wordComputation = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSMutableDictionary* duplicates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    for (int x = 1; x<=count; x++) {
        NSMutableArray* duplicateWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray* counter = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSString* key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x];
        NSArray* data = [linesDic objectForKey:key];
        numberOfwords = (int)[data count];
        numberOfDiffWords = numberOfwords;
        for (int j = 0; j<numberOfwords; j++) {
            for (int k = j+1; k<numberOfwords; k++) {
                if([[data objectAtIndex:k]isEqualToString:[data objectAtIndex:j]])
                {
                    numberOfDiffWords--;
                    [duplicateWords addObject:[data objectAtIndex:k]];
                    //                    NSLog(@"%@", [data objectAtIndex:k]);
                    //                    NSLog(@"%@", [data objectAtIndex:j]);
                }else{
                    NSString* a = [data objectAtIndex:k];
                    NSString* b = [data objectAtIndex:j];
                    if(a.length<b.length){
                        if((b.length - a.length)<=4){
                            if([[b substringToIndex:a.length]isEqualToString:a])
                            {
                                //                                NSLog(@"KEY: %@ comapare b:%d:%@ and a:%d:%@", key,(int)b.length, b, (int)a.length, a );
                                //                                NSLog(@"Key: %@, %@", key, [b substringFromIndex:(a.length-1)]);
                                if([[b substringFromIndex:(a.length)]isEqualToString:@"s"] || [[b substringFromIndex:(a.length)]isEqualToString:@"es"]){
                                    if (([a isEqualToString:@"a"] && [b isEqualToString:@"as"]))  {
                                        //                                        NSLog(@"break at key: %@, words %@:%@",key, a, b);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    numberOfDiffWords--;
                                    [duplicateWords addObject:[data objectAtIndex:k]];
                                    [duplicateWords addObject:[data objectAtIndex:j]];
                                    //                                    NSLog(@"%@", [data objectAtIndex:k]);
                                    //                                    NSLog(@"%@", [data objectAtIndex:j]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if((a.length - b.length)<=4){
                            if([[a substringToIndex:b.length]isEqualToString:b])
                            {
                                //                                NSLog(@"KEY: %@ compare a:%d: %@ and b:%d: %@", key,(int)a.length, a, (int)b.length, b );
                                //                                NSLog(@"Key: %@, %@", key, [a substringFromIndex:(b.length-1)]);
                                if([[a substringFromIndex:(b.length)]isEqualToString:@"s"] || [[a substringFromIndex:(b.length)]isEqualToString:@"es"]){
                                    if (([a isEqualToString:@"as"] && [b isEqualToString:@"a"])) {
                                        //                                        NSLog(@"break at key: %@, words %@:%@",key, a, b);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    numberOfDiffWords--;
                                    [duplicateWords addObject:[data objectAtIndex:k]];
                                    [duplicateWords addObject:[data objectAtIndex:j]];
                                    //                                    NSLog(@"%@", [data objectAtIndex:k]);
                                    //                                    NSLog(@"%@", [data objectAtIndex:j]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        NSNumber* nw = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numberOfwords];
        NSNumber* ndw = [NSNumber numberWithInt:numberOfDiffWords];
        [counter addObject:nw];
        [counter addObject:ndw];
        NSLog(@"Key: %@, Data: %@", key, duplicateWords);
        [duplicates setObject:duplicateWords forKey:key];
        [wordComputation setObject:counter forKey:key];
    }
    _duplicates = duplicates;
    NSLog(@"%@", _duplicates);
    _wordComputation = wordComputation;
    return wordComputation;
}

-(void)showTable:(NSMutableDictionary*)wordComputation{
    int count = (int)[wordComputation count];
    int numberOfwords = 0;
    int numberOfDiffWords = 0;
    //    NSLog(@"\t \t Diff Words  Words  Type Token \t Mean");
    for (int x = 1; x<=count; x++) {
        NSString* key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x];
        NSArray* data = [wordComputation objectForKey:key];
        numberOfwords = [[data objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
        numberOfDiffWords = [[data objectAtIndex:1]intValue];
        //print log
        //        NSLog(@"Line: %@ \t %@ \t %@ \t %@ \t\t %@", key, numberOfDiffWords<10?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", numberOfDiffWords]:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numberOfDiffWords], numberOfwords<10?[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", numberOfwords]:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numberOfwords],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d", numberOfDiffWords, numberOfwords], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d", numberOfwords, numberOfDiffWords]);
    }

    [_frequencyTable reloadData];
}
```

---

tried this just to change color for string first but then it shows

```
{
    NSColor = "NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
}
```

on the 5th position in string

---

```
- (IBAction)ViewDuplicatesPressed:(id)sender {
    [_duplicatesTextField setHidden:NO];
    NSLog(@"%@", _duplicates);


    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_contentTextField stringValue]] /*attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [NSColor redColor]}*/];


    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];



    [_duplicatesTextField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", attributedString]];
}
```

---

Also Tried

```
int lineCount = (int)[_linesDic count];
NSString* key;
NSMutableDictionary* dupliDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i<lineCount; i++) {
    NSArray *duplicateWords;
    key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    duplicateWords = [_duplicates objectForKey:key];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString;
    NSString* stringForKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_linesDic objectForKey:key]];
    for (int j =0 ; i < (int)[duplicateWords count]; j++) {
        NSString* word = [duplicateWords objectAtIndex:j];
        NSRange range = [stringForKey rangeOfString:word];
       attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_linesDic objectForKey:key]] /*attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [NSColor redColor]}*/];
        [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor redColor] range:range];
    }
    [dupliDic setObject:attributedString forKey:key];
}


[_duplicatesTextField setHidden:NO];
NSLog(@"%@", dupliDic);
[_duplicatesTextField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dupliDic]];
```

Comment: Ask a search expert about NSMutableAttributedString and NSMakeRange.  That's all I have to say for a person who doesn't show a single line of code.

Comment: tried those, showed edited code.. not working.. :/

Comment: also is it possible to get range of multiple words on multiple lines from the dictionary and set it in a loop to change colors for the duplicate words ?